# Json variable value is missing

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

i am new on android and i am working on application whose back end is in the php  mysql , now i have to send the success variable value to the android but it missed the values here is my php code

```
<?php

include_once("conn.php");  



$cdate=  date("Y-m-d");

//$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$uid = $_REQUEST['uid'];
$sql= "select * from user where user_id=$uid";
$result= mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){


$ldate = $row['created_date'];
}

$start = strtotime($ldate);

$end = strtotime($cdate);

$days_between = ceil(abs($end - $start) / 86400);
echo $days_between;
if($days_between<30){
$result= mysql_query($sql);
$json= array();


if(mysql_num_rows($result)){

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

//$json['emp_info'][]=$row;
}
$sval=1;
$mval=$rdays." days are remaining in expiration of your membership";
$json['emp_info']["suc"]=$sval;
$rdays= 30-$days_between;
$json['emp_info']["msg"]=$rdays." days are remaining in expiration of your membership";
}

echo json_encode($json);
}else{

//echo "you need to renew the membership";
$sval=0;
$mval="you need upgrade your membership to use the application";
$json= array();
$json['emp_info']["suc"]=$sval;
$json['emp_info']["msg"]=$mval;
echo json_encode($json); 
}
?>
```

and here is my android code to get the value of the json

```
   // Async Task to access the web
 private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
   try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
      response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
   }

   catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
  }

  private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
   String rLine = "";
   StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

   try {
    while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
     answer.append(rLine);
    }
   }

   catch (IOException e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("exception", "Exception is "+e.toString());
   }
   return answer;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   ListDrwaer();
  }
 }// end async task

 public void accessWebService() {
  JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
  // passes values for the urls string array
  task.execute(new String[] { url });
 }

 // build hash set for list view
 public void ListDrwaer() {
 // List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

  try {
   JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
   jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("emp_info");
   data = new String[jsonMainNode.length()];

   for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    String number = jsonChildNode.optString("user_id");
    ID = number;
    name = jsonChildNode.optString("suc");
    pass = jsonChildNode.optString("msg");
    Log.d("value", "values are"+name+pass);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "values"+name+pass, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     if(number.length()!=0){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Valeu of session before calling method "+session.IS_LOGIN, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

    session.IS_ID=ID;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "value of session id "+session.IS_ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent  intent = new Intent(MyDashboard.this, MyDashboard.class);
    intent.putExtra("ID", ID);



    //SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
    //String formattedDate =                ate)Format.parse(date);
    //datestr=formattedDate;
    //date.split(date);
    startActivity(intent);
    //dologin();
    //boolean value =true;  
    //session.createLoginSession(number, name,pass,true);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "value of sesesion after calling method"+session.IS_LOGIN, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Values"+name+number+pass, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //boolean value = false;
        //session.createLoginSession(number, name, pass, value);
    }
    String outPut = name /*+ "-" + number*/;
   // employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));
   //dologin();

    /*session.editor.putBoolean(session.IS_LOGIN, true);

    // Storing name in pref
    session.editor.putString(session.KEY_PASS, pass);
    // Storing id 
    session.editor.putString(session.IS_ID, ID);

    // Storing email in pref
    session.editor.putString(session.KEY_EMAIL, slemail);

    Log.d("Session", "Values of session"+slemail +ID+pass);
    // commit changes
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+session.IS_ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  // session.editor.commit();*/
   }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

 }
```

Now in the asynx task section it goes under the catch instead of the try :S

Comment: Show Your LogCat output or ErrorLog

Comment: @SilentKiller  10-25 03:08:52.409: D/Error(3298): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Waleed please provide full error block.

Comment: @SilentKiller my logcat have nothing then this everything is ok the thing is that it will not go into the try it goes to the catch

Comment: can you show me the full response..??\

Comment: @SilentKiller here it is 

10-25 03:08:46.679: I/Choreographer(3298): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-25 03:08:47.209: D/dalvikvm(3298): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 795K, 16% free 4781K/5684K, paused 198ms, total 233ms
10-25 03:08:47.619: D/dalvikvm(3298): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 188K, 17% free 4760K/5684K, paused 267ms
10-25 03:08:47.639: I/dalvikvm-heap(3298): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.002MB for 262160-byte allocation
10-25 03:08:47.829: D/dalvikvm(3298): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 16% free 5016K/5944K, paused 188ms, total 188ms

Comment: Waleed its an error that you are converting something which is not a JSONObject

Comment: @SilentKiller  
try {
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
    jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("emp_info");
    data = new String[jsonMainNode.length()];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
     String number = jsonChildNode.optString("user_id");
     ID = number;
     name = jsonChildNode.optString("suc");
     pass = jsonChildNode.optString("msg");
     Log.d("value", "values are"+name+pass);
   } catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.d("Error", ""+e.toString());

Comment: @SilentKiller so how to improve the code bcox the same way i was getting values from other files

Comment: JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

in this two line you are converting to JSONObject. may be you are converting here which is not an JSONObject. debug your app and check response.

Comment: Debug it and first check what response you are getting and what you are passing to JSONObject. this can solve your problem.. :)

Comment: thats y i ask the question by reading the message i can understand whats the issue

Comment: can you provide the result of PHP script execution?

Comment: @Tishka17 the same thing i was asking in my words as "response" :D

Comment: @Tishka17 http://aamirarif.com/organizer_json/mobile/test/testpayment.php?uid=72

Comment: @WaleedAhmed congratulation... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`emp_info` is not an array of objects so probably you cannot do  `JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);`

Probably you tried to print not

```
{"emp_info":[1,"2 days are remaining in expiration of your membership"]}
```

but

```
{"emp_info":[{"suc":1,"msg":"2 days are remaining in expiration of your membership"}]}
```

Try code like this:

```
$rdays= 30-$days_between;
array_push($json['emp_info'], array(
    "suc" => $sval;
    "msg" => $rdays." days are remaining in expiration of your membership"
))
```

Comment: try creating `$json['emp_info']` as `array` before doing `array_push`, it is something like:
 `$json['emp_info']=array();`

Comment: get sorted out that null this

Comment: @WaleedAhmed what it was?

Comment: syntax issue was there

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your php code I modified it a bit see if it works

```
<?php

require_once './db_connect.php';  //mine
$db = new DB_CONNECT();           //mine

$cdate=  date("Y-m-d");

//$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$uid = 1;//$_REQUEST['uid'];       //change to your and check if $_REQUEST IS SET
                                   //use if(isset($_POST["v_id"])) 

$sql= "select * from user where id=$uid";
$result= mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){


$ldate = $row['created_date'];
}

$start = strtotime($ldate);

$end = strtotime($cdate);

$days_between = ceil(abs($end - $start) / 86400);
//echo $days_between;
if($days_between<30){
$result= mysql_query($sql);
$json= array();


if(mysql_num_rows($result)){

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

//$json['emp_info'][]=$row;
}
$sval=1;

$rdays= 30-$days_between;  //this was below in original

$mval=$rdays." days are remaining in expiration of your membership";
$json['emp_info']["suc"]=$sval;
$rdays= 30-$days_between;
$json['emp_info']["msg"]=$rdays." days are remaining in expiration of your membership";
}

echo json_encode($json);
}else{

//echo "you need to renew the membership";
$sval=0;
$mval="you need upgrade your membership to use the application";
$json= array();
$json['emp_info']["suc"]=$sval;
$json['emp_info']["msg"]=$mval;
echo json_encode($json); 
}
?>
```

Comment: no this is not the solution my php is working fine http://aamirarif.com/organizer_json/mobile/test/testpayment.php?uid=72